# Probability of not winning, toys in cereal boxes

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A cereal company puts a star wars toy in each of its boxes as a sales promotion. 20 % of the cereal boxes contain a toy with Kylo Ren. You want a Kylo Ren toy.  So you buy 100 boxes of the cereal to be on the safe side. What is the probability that you dont win and what distribution do you use?

I am very confused by this because I wanted to use the negative binomial distribution and set it to have no successes in 100 trials, but i dont think that would work so if any one could please help me identify the correct distribution and help me set it up a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a binomial distribution. Introduce $X$ to be the random variable that denotes the number of [Kylo Ren](http://www.blastr.com/sites/blastr/files/styles/width_1280/public/kylo1.jpg) toys in $100$ boxes. With probability $20\ \%$, a given box has a Kylo Ren in it, so $X$ follows the distribution $\text{Bin}(100,0.20)$. The reason why I choose the binomial distribution is that any given box either contains Kylo Ren, or it does not, and we have independence between different boxes.

We want to find the probability $P(X=0)$, but using the binomial distribution, this is simply
$$P(X=0) = \binom{100}{0}(0.20)^0(0.80)^{100}=(0.80)^{100},$$
which by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280.8%29%5E100) turns out to be
$$2.037\cdot 10^{-10}.$$
Needless to say, this shows that it is *extremely* unlikely that you do not get at least one Kylo Ren in $100$ boxes.